# How can I make sure my python package looks for a file within its own directories as opposed to where I am running from?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a class object which has the task of running a file. When I was developing, my class object was in the same file as the code I used to run the file.

Now I am refactoring and making this a real package so I moved the code to a file called `class_objects.py`.

I have installed this package locally, but now when I use the class object `Naive` it looks for the file in the directory I am currently working in as opposed to looking for the file which is part of the package. I have read up on absolute paths, relative paths, and verifying that `__init__.py` exists. I am stumped on this one.

How can I make sure my package looks for the `file.ext` within its own directories as opposed to looking for `file.ext` where I am running from?

Here is how I call my package:

```py
# Trying to use my package installed locally

from my-package.class_objects import Naive


a = Naive()
a.find_and_run()
```

> Error

```
ValueError: no such file /home/user/tutorial/dir/file.ext
```

This is my directory

```py
My-Package
drwxrwxr-x    - user  8 Sep  1:27 .
drwxrwxr-x    - user  8 Sep  1:22 └── python
drwxrwxr-x    - user  8 Sep  1:25    ├── dist
.rw-r--r-- 1.6M user  8 Sep  1:25    │  ├── my-package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
.rw-rw-r-- 1.6M user  8 Sep  1:25    │  └── my-package-0.1.0.tar.gz
.rw-rw-r--  480 user  8 Sep  1:22    ├── pyproject.toml
drwxrwxr-x    - user  8 Sep  1:24    └── my-package
.rw-rw-r--    0 user  8 Sep  1:14       ├── __init__.py
.rw-rw-r-- 2.6k user  8 Sep  1:13       ├── class_objects.py
drwxrwxr-x    - user  8 Sep  1:19       ├── dir
.rw-rw-r--    0 user  8 Sep  1:19       │  ├── __init__.py
.rwxrwxr-x 1.5M user  7 Sep 22:39       │  ├── file.exe
```

This is what is inside of `class_objects.py`

```py
class Naive(object):
   ...
   def find_and_run():
        out_dir = os.path.join("dir", "file.ext")
        naive_model = RunThing(stan_file=out_dir)
```

Comment: Have you tried `inspect.stack`? `inspect.stack()[0]` will give you the file which ran the inspect stack code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inspect.stack` to get information about the stack, including the current file

```py
# foo.py
from bar import this
```

```
# bar.py
def this():
   pass

import inspect 
print(inspect.stack()[0].filename)
# C:/my_git/stack/bar.py # it returns the absolute path
```

So from `foo` you can import your package `bar` which can be aware of where `bar` is.

Comment: Sorry I think I answered the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution with `pkg_resources.resource_filename`

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename

class Naive(object):
   ...
   def find_and_run():
        out_dir = resource_filename('dir', 'file.ext')
        naive_model = RunThing(stan_file=out_dir)
```